# Sort and filter a collection of songs

Tags: arraylist

Here is the link for the assignment:
pastelink.me/dl/bf6659#sthash.LtZIJpI7.dpuf

I need to complete the SongCollection class to reach the second checkpoint.  I'm really new at coding and I'm not very good at it so I really appreciate all of your answers! Thank you so much. Here is the work I have done so far:

Main class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GazillionSongs {
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        System.out.println("Hello.  This program will sort and filter large databases of popular songs.  Please enter an input file.");
        Scanner file = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userSelection = file.nextLine();

        if (userSelection.toLowerCase().contains("gazillion")){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/julie_000/workspace/juliet/bin/agazillionsongs.txt"));
        String user = input.nextLine();

        Song songObject = new Song(user);
        System.out.println(songObject.toString());

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
        System.out.println("File not found"); 
    }
}
}
```

Song class:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Song {
private static int year;
private static int rank;
private static String artist;
private static String title;

public Song(String s){
    StringTokenizer parseLine = new StringTokenizer(s, "\t");
    String strYear = parseLine.nextToken();
    year = Integer.parseInt(strYear);
    String strRank = parseLine.nextToken();
    rank = Integer.parseInt(strRank);
    artist = parseLine.nextToken();
    title = parseLine.nextToken();

}

public int getYear(){
    return year;
}

public int getRank(){
    return rank;
}

public String getArtist(){
    return artist;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}

public String toString(){
    return String.format(year + "\t" + rank + "\t" + artist + "\t" + title);

    }
}
```

SongCollection class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SongCollection {

public SongCollection(ArrayList<Song> songs){
    SongCollection objects = new SongCollection(songs);
}

public void filterYear(Range r){

}

public void filterRank(Range r){

}

public void filterArtist(String s){

}

public void filterTitle(String s){

}

public void sortYear(){

}

public void sortRank(){

}

public void sortArtist(){

}

public void sortTitle(){

}

public String toString(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for sorting your entries use Comparator Interface, for filtering your entries i would suggest to write your own filters. 
I made a small example for you:

You Entityclass Song, i only add another contructor:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Song implements Comparable<Song>{

    private int year;
    private int rank;
    private String artist;
    private String title;

    public Song(final int year, final int rank, final String title, final String artist) {
        this.year   = year;
        this.rank   = rank;
        this.title  = title;
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public Song(String s){
        StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s, "\t");
        String strYear = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
        year = Integer.parseInt(strYear);
        String strRank = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
        rank = Integer.parseInt(strRank);
        title = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
        artist = stringTokenizer.nextToken();

    }

    public int getYear(){
        return year;
    }

    public int getRank(){
        return rank;
    }

    public String getArtist(){
        return artist;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format(year + "\t" + rank + "\t" + artist + "\t" + title);

    }

    public int compareTo(Song o) {
        if(this.getYear() < o.getYear()) 
            return -1;
        if(this.getYear() > o.getYear()) 
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The SongCollection class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import de.professional_webworkx.blog.cddb.comparators.ArtistComparator;
import de.professional_webworkx.blog.cddb.comparators.YearComparator;
import de.professional_webworkx.blog.cddb.model.Song;

public class SongCollection<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7754560588028902292L;

    public SongCollection() {

    }

    public void addSong(final T song) {
        this.add(song);
    }

    public T getSong(final int idx) {
        return this.get(idx);
    }

    public List<T> sortByArtist() {
        Collections.sort((List<Song>)this, new ArtistComparator());
        return this;
    }

    public List<T> sortByYear() {
        Collections.sort((List<Song>)this, new YearComparator());
        return this;
    }

}
```

As you can see, i implemented two methods, sortByArtist() and sortByYear with the corresponding Artist- and YearComparator(), which i post below:

ArtistComparator

```
import java.util.Comparator;

import de.professional_webworkx.blog.cddb.model.Song;

public class ArtistComparator implements Comparator<Song> {

    public int compare(Song o1, Song o2) {

        int ret = o1.getArtist().compareTo(o2.getArtist());

        if(ret > 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        if(ret < 1) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

YearComparator

```
import java.util.Comparator;

import de.professional_webworkx.blog.cddb.model.Song;

public class YearComparator implements Comparator<Song> {

    public int compare(Song o1, Song o2) {
        if(o1.getYear() < o2.getYear()) 
            return -1;
        if(o1.getYear() > o2.getYear()) 
            return 1;

        return 0;
    }

}
```

Now, if you want to filter your entries, i suggest to use an IFilter Interface:

IFilter:

```
public interface IFilter<T> {

    public boolean accept(T filter);
}
```

BetweenFilter which implements the IFilter IF:

```
public class BetweenFilter<T extends Object & Comparable<T>> implements IFilter<T> {

    private T lowBoundary;
    private T highBoundary;

    public BetweenFilter(final T lowBoundary, final T highBoundary) {
        this.lowBoundary    = lowBoundary;
        this.highBoundary   = highBoundary;
    }

    public boolean accept(T object) {
        return lowBoundary.compareTo(object) <= 0 &&
                highBoundary.compareTo(object) >= 0;
    }

}
```

Now we need a nice small Utils class, i named it FilterUtils, to apply different filters:

FilterUtils:
This class gets your list with entries and  the filter which should be applied and iterates over the list, if the current value matches it will be add to the result list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FilterUtils {

    public static <T> List<T> applyFilter(final List<T> list, final IFilter<T> filter) {

        final List<T> filteredList = new ArrayList<T>();
        for(final T val : list) {
            if(filter.accept(val)) {
                filteredList.add(val);
            }
        }

        return filteredList;

    }
}
```

And now, lets try it:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import de.professional_webworkx.blog.cddb.filter.BetweenFilter;
import de.professional_webworkx.blog.cddb.filter.BetweenYearFilter;
import de.professional_webworkx.blog.cddb.filter.FilterUtils;
import de.professional_webworkx.blog.cddb.filter.IFilter;
import de.professional_webworkx.blog.cddb.model.Song;

public class SongListManager {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SongCollection<Song> collection = new SongCollection<Song>();
        try {


                Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("data/agazillionsongs.txt"));
                String line = "";
                while(input.hasNextLine()) {
                    String user = input.nextLine();

                    collection.add(new Song(user));
                }

            for(Song song : collection) {
                System.out.println(song);
            }

            System.out.println("Filtered by Artist");
            List<Song> filteredByArtist = collection.sortByArtist();
            for(Song song : filteredByArtist) {
                System.out.println(song);
            }
            IFilter<Song> betweenFilter = new BetweenFilter<Song>(new Song(1999, 1, "Hyper Hyper", "Scooter"), new Song(2001, 23, "Title", "DemoArtist"));
            List<Song> applyFilter = FilterUtils.applyFilter(filteredByArtist, betweenFilter);

            System.out.println("With applied Filter");
            for(Song val : applyFilter) 
                System.out.println(val);

            IFilter<Song> betweenYears  = new BetweenYearFilter<Song>(2010, 2013);
            List<Song> betweenYearsFiltered = FilterUtils.applyFilter(collection, betweenYears);

            System.out.println("With applied years filter");
            for(Song song : betweenYearsFiltered) {
                System.out.println(song);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
            System.out.println("File not found"); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the code in [this Repository](https://github.com/PatrickOtt/SongListManager).

Hope this example code will help you.